# Very-large-list manager (iOS/mobile)

Tags: ios, information-management, iphone-app, ipad-app

If anyone is familiar with iOS's [**TaskBook**](http://shibuymenglish.blogspot.com/p/taskbook.html), it's a list/task manager with some convenient features that have become crucial to my workflow (lists typically contain hundreds up to 1000+ items).

Unfortunately, it is no longer in active development, so I need a replacement… but it has become difficult-to-impossible to find all of these features in one app.

#### Must have

1. Runs on iPhone and iPad *with* automatic syncing
2. Must allow a *manual* sort order
3. ***Hard to find!*** — Instantly send any item directly to the top or bottom of the list (both would be ideal)
4. ***Hard to find!*** — Instantly scroll (jump) to the top **or bottom** of the list
   (scroll-to-top is built into iOS, but not scroll-to-bottom)
5. Quickly assign/reassign tags or categories to items (drag-and-drop in and out of tags is ideal)
6. Search within a list (incremental search-as-you-type preferred)

#### Nice to have

- Misc. notes attached to items (with an excerpt or indicator on the main list)
- Quick tagging/untagging on main screen without a lot of context-switching
- Tap-hold-drag to reorder items (without switching to an 'edit' mode with drag-handles)
- Add items to the top or bottom of the list (not critical if I get #3 above)
- Batch tagging or categorizing
- Tags or categories show how many items are assigned to it

Comment: Check [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/). I don't have time for a complete answer now.

Comment: @JanDoggen Wunderlist does *not* have the hard-to-find items #3 and #4 (unless I'm missing something), otherwise it's comparable to any list manager. Thank you for the suggestion but doesn't meet my needs.